# as anything else?

Tags: grammar

I can't get the meaning of some expressions including 
"as anything else" in a sentence below.

"As problematically, the U.S. didn't even play well so their attempts at being proactive or dictating anything became an exercise in them chasing the game, looking as stunned by Argentina as anything else. "

1. I don't know what exactly the expression "as anything else" refers to or modifies in its meaning in the same sentence.(not outside this sentence since all I got is this sentence).
   I mean, does it mean that the U.S. is stunned by other problems presented by Argentina(as anything else) or does "as anything else" modifies "stunned," meaning it got many other impacts by Argentina and of all the influences it was "stunned?".
2. became an exercise in them chasing the game
   -> 
   Does "become an exercise" mean that it was done on a regular basis to the point where it became like a regular routine? (in this case, meaning that the U.S. lost control over this matter and incompetent?)

   Thank you for reading it and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

1/ The expression "as anything else", sometimes written as "as much as anything else" is used to identify one (or more) reasons for an event. It effectively says that there was more than one reason for the event, but the reason (or reasons) specified are as important as any other.

In this case, the event is the U.S. not playing well. some examples of their bad play are specified, then the reason for the bad play is given as "stunned by Argentina". So the writer is saying, there are probably several reasons for the U.S. playing badly, but the fact that they had to play against Argentina is one of the major reasons.

2/ Yes, you have the essence of it. The expression is usually used to indicate that someone was trying to do something positive, but it repeatedly ended up being something negative, eg "Trying to get him to see reason was just an exercise in frustration."

Comment: thank you so much for your time and really detailed answer!